# PostgreSQL cross join using max returns null

Tags: sql, postgresql, max, cross-join

I want to select the max() value of the modified_at column in each of several tables:

```
select 
max(a.modified_at) as a_modified_at,
max(b.modified_at) as b_modified_at,  
max(c.modified_at) as c_modified_at 
from a, b, c;
```

This works correctly as long as each of the tables has at least 1 row.
The problem is that when just one of the tables has 0 rows, null is returned for all tables:

```
null,null,null
```

What is a solution that returns the correct values for the tables that do have rows?
PostgreSQL-10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `OUTER JOIN`s should do it

```
select 
max(a.modified_at) as a_modified_at,
max(b.modified_at) as b_modified_at,  
max(c.modified_at) as c_modified_at 
from a outer join b outer join c;
```

but a possibly simpler option would be to use 3 subqueries instead:

```
select 
(select max(modified_at) from a) as a_modified_at,
(select max(modified_at) from b) as b_modified_at,  
(select max(modified_at) from c) as c_modified_at;
```

Comment: I like the subqueries solution better. It is more efficient, since it does not multiply the rows before aggregation, as both OP's attempt and the `outer join` solution do.

Comment: @GMB I kinda would have expected Postgres to be smart enough to optimise the cartesian product away, knowing that the aggregate function is not affected by duplicate values. But I trust your instincts better than mine :-)

Comment: The second solution should be the primary. There is no relation between a/b/c wanted here here